# How to create Bitbucket pull request in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, visual-studio, bitbucket, pull-request

I want to create a Pull Request in Visual Studio 2019 for a Bitbucket repository but I couldn't find anything for that.

I used these extensions:

- Visual Studio Bitbucket
- Git Web Links
- DevDiary

But nothing works for me and these extensions have no Pull Request option.